# How to localize data from Cloud Firestore for iOS app

Tags: firebase, localization, google-cloud-firestore

I am now making an iOS app with localized support. I have all the data stored on Firebase (Cloud firestore). It is funny now, how can I translate the strings to other language (just like swap the Localizable.strings files within app)?

Should I have the different languages files on Firebase then swap between them?

Any idea?